# Average on table joined with right join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to average on tables I joined with right join, but I get group by error, I tried grouping by column I got the error but it still didn't work

```sql
Select 
t1.[TimeCol],
t1.[table1sampleColumn] AS t1sC,
AVG(t1.[table1sampleColumn]) as avgt1sC,
t2.[table2sampleColumn] AS t2sC,
AVG(t2.[table2sampleColumn]) as avgt2sC,
t2.[table2sampleColumn2] as t2sC2,
AVG(t2.[table2sampleColumn2]) as avgt2sC2


FROM dbo.table1 t1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
ON CAST(t1.TimeCol AS SMALLDATETIME) = CAST(t2.LocalCol AS SMALLDATETIME)

WHERE t1.TimeCol BETWEEN '2022-01-27 07:00:00' and '2022-01-27 07:05:00'
ORDER BY TimeCol DESC
```

The query works when there are no AVG, but I want to AVG. how can I do that

error:

```
Column 'dbo.table1.TimeCol' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

my result without averaging

```
TimeCol                    t1sC     t2sC t2sC2
2022-01-27 07:04:13.850    271      164   299
2022-01-27 07:03:13.850    271      167   299
2022-01-27 07:02:13.847    269      170   298
2022-01-27 07:01:13.840    269      173   297
2022-01-27 07:00:13.830    269      176   296
```

the output i want with average

```
TimeCol                        t1sC    avgt1sC  t2sC   avgt2sC  t2sC2  avgt2sC2
2022-01-27 07:04:13.850        271      270     164    170      299    298
2022-01-27 07:03:13.850        271              167             299    
2022-01-27 07:02:13.847        269              170             298    
2022-01-27 07:01:13.840        269              173             297    
2022-01-27 07:00:13.830        269              176             296
```

Comment: The `RIGHT JOIN` is an implicit `INNER JOIN` here due to your `WHERE`.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: As for the error, it is *literally* telling you the problem; what about the error don't you understand here? You *can't* use a (non-windowed) aggregate and have non-aggregated values in the same `SELECT` without a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: *"Does this have anything to do with the problem?"* Considering your title implies that the `RIGHT JOIN` is part of the problem, "Average on table joined with right join", I would assume so. If the `RIGHT JOIN` is *working as intended*, why highlight it in the title, and why have a `RIGHT JOIN` when it should be an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @Larnu I don't know much about sql, I was wondering if using "right join" would prevent averaging?

Comment: No, the error is telling you what's preventing you: *"Column 'dbo.table1.TimeCol' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."* Though it's erroring at the first non-aggregated/not grouped column, it'll also error on `t1.[table1sampleColumn]`, `t2.[table2sampleColumn]` and `t2.[table2sampleColumn2]`. The fact your want to aggregate and not-aggregate ont the same column suggests you need a windowed aggregate; but without sampled data and expected results, we won't know.

Comment: That's not a right join. The `WHERE` clause defeats the outer join.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I select some sections in a table like the 5 minute portion as it appears in the WHERE row, I want the data in the columns here individually (1 row per minute) and the average of the 5 minutes

Comment: @AaronBertrand It doesn't matter that you can write the average in each row along the column in the average column. the important thing is to write the average

Comment: Why does only the top row have an average? Why don't the rest?

Comment: what do you mean by top row, is it the 5 minute part in the WHERE condition?

Comment: The row at the top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a windowed aggregate here, which would look like this:

```sql
Select  t1.[TimeCol],
        t1.[table1sampleColumn] AS t1sC,
        AVG(t1.[table1sampleColumn]) OVER () as avgt1sC,
        t2.[table2sampleColumn] AS t2sC,
        AVG(t2.[table2sampleColumn]) OVER () as avgt2sC,
        t2.[table2sampleColumn2] as t2sC2,
        AVG(t2.[table2sampleColumn2]) OVER () as avgt2sC2
FROM dbo.table1 t1
     INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON CAST(t1.TimeCol AS SMALLDATETIME) = CAST(t2.LocalCol AS SMALLDATETIME) --This doesn't look right, and likely need improving
WHERE t1.TimeCol >= '2022-01-27T07:00:00'
  AND t1.TimeCol <= '2022-01-27 07:05:00' --I assume you do want <= here, as you used BETWEEN, but you probably actually want <
ORDER BY TimeCol DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works as i want

You said that combining the time columns with smalldatetime seems wrong, (I am writing a query on the existing database) There are 20 tables, there is a time column formed with data from a system that receives data every minute. When merging by time, if I don't do smalldatetime, when I join directly with join, there is a problem because they are not in the same second (example 2 time data; for table1 2022-01-27 07:04:13.850 for table2 2022-01-27 07:04:24.341)

Comment: if possible (not so important) is there a chance to write the average of t1sC at the top of the t1sC column example column 150 148 149 150 151 152 (top 150 average)

Comment: I asked you about that in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73278190/average-on-table-joined-with-right-join/73278688?noredirect=1#comment129413490_73278190), @EmreOz , you didn't reply, so I have not applied that logic. You could use a `CASE` expression on `ROW_NUMBER` or do this in your presentation layer.

Comment: First of all, sorry for my late reply. I thought you were asking for it to write multiple or 1 times in the "avgt1sC" column in your comment above. What I want to write at the top of the column is in the "t1sC" column. so the average will be directly in the column itself. In the t1sC column, Average-Data1-Data2-Data3....

Comment: As i mentioned, you could use a `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER`, @EmreOz . In pseudo-SQL: `CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...) WHEN 1 THEN AVG(...) ... END`

Answer (score -2):

It is not working thus you did not use group by clause. You should use it and include all other columns(t1.[TimeCol],t1.[table1sampleColumn],t2.[table2sampleColumn],t2.[table2sampleColumn2]) to the group by clause.

Comment: When grouping them all with GROUP BY, it does not average, writes the same results again

avgt2sC results with t2sC;
164 164
167 167
170 170
173 173
176 176

Comment: Then what is the point in the `AVG` of `t2.[table2sampleColumn]` if you are going to put it in the `GROUP BY`? The average of a single value is that single value; no matter how many times that value is repeated. This *can't* be the answer, as the you are grouping and averaging the same values.

Comment: so how do i get the average